# is there a way to import { pool } from pg

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import Pool, but i am getting an error.

This is the error, which get thrown:

```
import { Pool } from "pg";
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Pool' not found. The requested module 'pg' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
```

This is my code:

```js
import { Pool } from "pg";

dotenv.config();

const databaseConfig = { connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL };
const pool = new Pool(databaseConfig);

export default pool;
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use the default export:

```
import pg from "pg";
const { Pool } = pg;

dotenv.config();

const databaseConfig = { connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL };
const pool = new Pool(databaseConfig);

export default pool;
```